# sendSynchronousRequest method return null data on simulator but it's working fine on real device?

Tags: ios, xcode, https

I have strange problem

when I run app on real device I got data from sendSynchronousRequest with response code 200

but when i run app on simulator it returns null data with response code zero

when I run same project on another machine it working fine for both simulator and real device.

same time I can use facebook and gmail from safari on simulator. so there is internet connection problem.

appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your machine has internet connection issue. Simulator uses your machines internet connection..

Hope this helps

Comment: I can use facebook from my simulator same time and it's working fine